# Python ModuleNotFoundError when trying to import a method from an outer directory of different level

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.6.0 and `pipenv`.
I have a python project called `myapp` in pycharm and the directory structure is

```
- myapp
 - src
   - __init__.py
   - server.py
   - module
    - __init__.py
    - utils.py
    - model
      - __init__.py
      - model.py
 - tests
   - module
    - model
      - __init__.py
      - test_model.py
```

To make it clearer, `src` and `tests` are directories of the same level, and **init**.py is present in every level of the directory. The `main()` method below is inside `model.py`

```py
def main():
  from src.module.utils import get_method_from_utils
  from tests.module.model.test_model import to_json
```

`from src.module.utils import get_method_from_utils` works

but `from tests.module.model.test_model import to_json` doesn't

When I right click on `main()` and click `Run 'model'` on pycharm, it will return `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.module'` I suspect it is because `tests` is actually located in the outer level of `model`. I tried something like `from ... import tests.module.model.test_model.to_json` to return to the outer level of directory but it doesn't work. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tests` folder should be a package to import it. Try adding `__init__.py` file to make it a package. You can learn more about Python packages  [Here](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages).

Comment: if it doesn't have `__init__.py`, what is it called? isit called just a directory instead of a python package?

Comment: Yes, if folder have `__init__.py` it is called a package.